# Escape the last Delimiter from the string

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dynamic form with corresponding check box with each row.

```
Plan    Price   Choose
PHP       $3     []
.Net      $2     []
C#        $6     []
Java      $2     []
C++       $10    []
ROR       $2     []
```

User can Select multiple checkbox, then selected plans will show on the next page like

Output

```
Java,C++,ROR,
```

Code used for Output

```
<?php foreach ($_POST['check_list'] as $id => $plan_name) {
      echo $id;
      echo ','; 
     }
 ?>
```

It contains the ',' at last. I want to leave that comma at the end.

Desired Output:

```
Java,C++,ROR
```

what should I do to get the desired output?

Comment: `rtrim` or simply implode the keys of `$_POST` (the second one is slightly easier in my opinion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rtrim($string, ",");
```

This will remove all "," at the end of the string.

EDIT:
Well, after i looked more on the code i see i'm wrong ^

```
<?php
$lastkey = key(array_slice($_POST['check_list'], -1, 1, TRUE));
foreach ($_POST['check_list'] as $id => $plan_name) {
    echo $id;
    if ($id !== $lastkey)
        echo ','; 
}
?>
```

Comment: where should I apply rtrim,                                                                     <?php foreach ($_POST['check_list'] as $id => $plan_name) {
      echo $id;
      echo ','; 
     }
 ?>

Comment: it's coming up like PHP,.NetC#,JavaC++,ROR

Comment: I just clicked on the Acceptance, I thought I can click 2 Acceptance, but the moment I saw it again it was unchecked, I was in the process of clicking yours... You did awesome work with quick response... Cheers to u.

Answer (score 4):

No need for a loop - `implode` and `array_keys` will do what you need:

```
echo implode(array_keys($_POST['check_list']));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$checked = $_POST['check_list'];
<?php
     foreach ($checked as $id => $plan_name) {
         echo $id;
         if (end($checked) !== $plan_name)
             echo ',';
     }
?>
```